# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Installations

Tags: 16.04, software-center

I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu software installations, as I haven't used it in a while. I'm having trouble getting the software center to work. It opens, and starts loading, and just closes. Not sure what the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try running software-center?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like synaptic,another package manager,which you can install that by running

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```